# Meaning of "very time"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Would anybody like to discuss the usage of **very time**? I googled to know about it, but I didn't find anything about. Please, say the proper usage of **at this very time/at that very time**.

Sorry, no context is available.

Comment: the use of 'very' is simply to emphasize on that exact time. Not a second earlier, not a second later. That exact time.

Answer (score 1):

I think *"At this very time"* means:

> At this **exact** time.

"very" is used for emphasis. So by saying *'at this very time'* simply means *'at this exact, precise time'*. It means *'now'* and the stress is given to show the emphasis on the present time.